Confusion in 2D Poisson equation step
For the Poisson equation in 2D:
$$
- \Delta u = f
$$
we have that the solution is given by:
$$
u(x) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R^2}} \log(|x-y|) f(y) dy
$$
In my notes, they calculate:
$$
\nabla u(x) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R^2}} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|} f(y) dy
$$
Should it not be:
$$
\nabla u(x) = -\frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{\mathbb{R^2}} \frac{x-y}{|x-y|^2} f(y) dy
$$

Yes, the equation given in your notes is incorrect.
